# Parse JSON as string using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am using Retrofit and RxJava as REST client. It works wonderfully. But, in my app I also scan QR code where the result is a JSON object as string. Sure I can parse it using GSON but there but I wish to use more clean code. So, how can I parse JSON so that I receive as String using retrofit (I seen only how to use it from URL), how do I use it locally?

Comment: Do you want to send the QR code String via Retrofit to a REST server?
Did you add GSON as converter to Retrofit? 
What type are you getting back from the Retrofit interface? Observable<String>? Observable<ResponseBody>? Or a custom type?

Comment: No, I do not wish to send QR code to server, just scan it, parse and use as Object of the same type as other objects I receive from server. No, I did not added GSON as converter and I prefer not to use GSON at all. From retrofit I get Observable<List<Movie>> where Movie is custom type.

Comment: To map String to Object you need an Object Mapper. You can either do it yourself or use e.g. GSON, Moshi or Jackson. Retrofit itself does not do JSON (De-)Serialization and Object Mapping. It needs converters for that. Out of the box it can only return ResponseBody. Assuming RxJava CallAdapter is applied, you would only be able to use Observable<ResponseBody> as return type in your interface. Since you are able to use Observable<List<Movie>> it seems like you've added an Converter to Retrofit. Do you mind sharing your code which creates the Retrofit instance and/or your build.gradle file?